# module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'unique_object_name' keras error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error:
"module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'unique_object_name"

when I run this block:

```
    if not name:
      self._name = backend.unique_object_name(
          generic_utils.to_snake_case(self.__class__.__name__),
          zero_based=zero_based)
    else:
      backend.unique_object_name(name)
      self.name = name
```

this is what I'm importing:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2 as tf

import collections
import copy
import functools
import itertools
import threading
import warnings
import weakref


import numpy as np

from google.protobuf import json_format
from tensorflow.python.eager import execute
from keras import backend
from keras import constraints
from keras import initializers
from keras import regularizers
from keras.engine import base_layer_utils
from keras.engine import input_spec
from keras.engine import keras_tensor
from keras.engine import node as node_module
from keras.mixed_precision import autocast_variable
from keras.mixed_precision import loss_scale_optimizer
from keras.mixed_precision import policy
from keras.saving.saved_model import layer_serialization
from keras.utils import generic_utils
from keras.utils import layer_utils
from keras.utils import object_identity
from keras.utils import tf_inspect
from keras.utils import tf_utils
from keras.utils import version_utils
# A module that only depends on `keras.layers` import these from here.
from keras.utils.generic_utils import to_snake_case  # pylint: disable=unused-import
from keras.utils.tf_utils import is_tensor_or_tensor_list  # pylint: disable=unused-import
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging
from tensorflow.python.training.tracking import base as trackable
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import get_canonical_name_for_symbol
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
from tensorflow.tools.docs import doc_controls
```

I know an easy fix is to downgrade the versions of tensorflow and keras that I am using but I want to avoid doing that. I am using version 2.5.0 of both tensorflow and keras.

Comment: use `from tensorflow.keras import backend` instead of `from keras import backend`. Hope to work.

Comment: That did not work. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Replace all `keras.*` imports with `tensorflow.keras.*` imports.

Comment: That also did not work. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Hi ! I am able to  import unique_object_name from from keras.,backend in 2.5 with TF 2.5 in Colab,used your code in a  class  . Could you also provide your complete code for solving the issue .You can also go through below gist for reference https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/7d8da7d38c53a909b8d72933f4dfd203/stack_68290868.ipynb